# Correct way to handle a Partial Record with iteration not showing undefined in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to find the correct way to type a logical Dictionary object in TypeScript. The `Record` and `Partial` types combined do not work the way I want them to -- my "want" is to behave like a common dictionary/map available in other languages.

Given a `dict: Dictionary<K,V>` I want:

- `dict.key` to have the type `undefined|V` since the key may not exist
- `Object.values(dict)` to have the type `Iterable<V>`
- `Object.entries(dict)` to have the type `Iterable<[K, V]>`
- `Object.keys(dict)` to have the type `Iterable<K>`

`Record<K,V>` does not work, since accessing by key always yields the value type `V`, even though the key may not exist.

`Partial<Record<K,V>>` does not work, since then `Object.values` returns a type of `Iterable<V|undefined>`

How can I properly define a `Dictionary` type that works with standard JS objects?

It's fine if I have to override definitions of `Object.values/entries/keys` for a Dictionary type. I'm not clear on how I override `Object` functions for specific types only.

*Note: I'm aware of a lot of the history of these types here. I'm interested in finding a solution that works. The above Dictionary is a common typing paradigm available in many languages, so I would like it to be possible in TypeScript.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment there appears to be no way to properly model a Dictionary type in TypeScript.

A [question](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44361) on the TypeScript project indicates `noUncheckedIndexedAccess` as an option, but that's a global flag that goes beyond records and flags some valid array use as well.